# Powershell change format of csv file

Tags: powershell, csv, replace, multiple-users

I need some help on the ordering/removal of csv file and its data.
The output file looks like this:

```
@{UserPrincipalName=name.surname@domain.com}
@{UserPrincipalName=name1.surname1@domain.com}
@{UserPrincipalName=name2.surname2@domain.com}
```

however what I like to get is the following:

```
'name.surname@domain.com', 'name1.surname1@domain.com', 'name2.surname2@domain.com'
```

I tried it with replace, trim and other commands however no success so far. Here my AAD scripts which I use to get the users.

```
Write-Host "Fetching data from Azure Active Directory..."
$cred = New-Object -TypeName PSCredential -argumentlist $username, $pwd
#Connect to M365
Connect-MsolService -Credential $cred
$Users = Get-MsolUser -All | Where-Object { $_.UserType -ne "Guest" }
$userlist = [System.Collections.Generic.List[Object]]::new() # Create output file
ForEach ($User in $Users) {

    $ReportLine = [PSCustomObject] @{
        UserPrincipalName  = $User.UserPrincipalName
    }
                
    $userlist.Add($ReportLine)
    }

$Output = "c:\logging\data\AAD_Users_only.csv"
Set-Content -path $Output -value $userlist
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Why not just 1 Line?:
`Get-MSOLUser | Where-Object { $_.UserType -ne "Guest" } | Select-Object UserPrincipalName | Export-Csv c:\logging\data\AAD_Users_only.csv`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply replace the last line:

```
Set-Content -path $Output -value $userlist
```

With:

```
$userlist |Export-Csv -LiteralPath $output -NoTypeInformation
```

`Export-Csv` will inspect the properties on the input objects, find that they only have a `UserPrincipalName` property, and output that as the only column in the resulting CSV file:

```
UserPrincipalName
name.surname@domain.com
name1.surname1@domain.com
name2.surname2@domain.com
```

To read the values back into memory, use `Import-Csv`:

```
PS ~> $UPNs = Import-Csv path\to\AAD_Users_only.csv
PS ~> $UPNs

UserPrincipalName
-----------------
name.surname@domain.com
name1.surname1@domain.com
name2.surname2@domain.com
```